# Issue with Cloth and Hook Connection for Animation

Tags: animation, modifiers, cloth-simulation

Apologies as I'm still fairly new to blender, but I'm learning fast!

I'm trying to animate this cable to be pulled tight when another object that it is attached to moves forward. I have a hook set-up but unfortunately, I cannot get it to move with the animation. I've tried reorganizing the modifiers as some forms have suggested but nothing seems to work. [Here is a link to the blend file.](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1XVgQqUOKnNdu5eO7dSTftB4sO7Mh35SD/view?usp=sharing)

[image]

[image]

Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: Do you think you could upload your blend file so I could look through it and try and figure out whats wrong easier?

Comment: There should be link in the description but i may not have done it right. Here is a drive link: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1XVgQqUOKnNdu5eO7dSTftB4sO7Mh35SD/view?usp=sharing

edit: Thank you kind stranger for the help!

Comment: Oh youre right, I'm just used to drive links being at the bottom of the question. Will check file now.

Comment: oh my bad! Sorry, for the bad formating.

Comment: Managed to get the cloth to follow along with the hook, currently testing if it sticks to animation.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem stems from the cloth physics cache only baking to frame 250, in the blend file you sent I increased this limit and now it stretches with the hook object as intended. I also did some complimentary mesh cleanup as many of your objects have bloated geometry and overlapping vertices. In future also remember to reset some value of your physics sim in order to reset and rebake it if you find things aren't changing.

Link to fixed blend file.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1wwrORCaKK0TmbGw5CIhmpXpMH3zHCKp8/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Omg your the best! Thank you so much!

Comment: No problem, good luck with your project.